# Google Apps Script will not pass data with dates to HTML form

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code on my HTML file which runs when I click a button. The idea is to pass data from the worksheet to the HTML form.

```
function getExistingTask(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(aftergetExistingTask).getTaskData();
        
      }

      function aftergetExistingTask(values){
        window.alert(values);
        document.getElementById("idWBS").value = values[0][1];
        document.getElementById("idTaskName").value = values[0][2];
        document.getElementById("idResourceName").value = values[0][3];
        document.getElementById("idPercDone").value = values[0][8];
        document.getElementById("idNotes").value = values[0][0];
        document.getElementById("idPreds").value = values[0][7];
        document.getElementById("idFromRow").value = values[0][9];
      }
```

The above code calls

```
//Get the data of for the active row based on activecell
function getTaskData(){
  try{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("ProjectPlan");
  var ac = ss.getActiveCell();
  var ar = ac.getRow();
  var values = ws.getRange(ar,NOTESCOL,1,PERCDONECOL-NOTESCOL+1).getValues();
  values[0].push(ar);
  //alertMessage(values);
  return values;}
  catch(err){
    console.log("stuff",err.message);
  }
}
```

This works great IF I do not have any dates in the range. However if I have dates nothing is returned to my HTML form.

`window.alert(values);` shows the array data when no dates are in the range, but when I select a row that has dates, the alert simply has "null" in it.

Why aren't dates possible to pass, and how do I get around this as I need to be able to pass dates?

I've tried searching for answers online but have not found any threads that speak to my issue.

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet with data?

Comment: From your situation of `window.alert(values); shows the array data when no dates are in the range, but when I select a row that has dates, the alert simply has "null" in it.`, I thought that this thread might be the answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56480228

Comment: See [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) you can not pass Date object to client.

Comment: Maybe use `getDisplayValues()`to get the dates, since getting it as object turns it into an "illegal" data to passed from server-side to client-side [here is bit on it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

Comment: Related (homework?) question: [How to write data to a range of cells in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75691900/1330560)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all that replied!
I continued to dig and found the answer. Dates cannot be sent, the payload must be put into JSON.stringify(), then on the HTML side pull out the dates.

```js
function getTaskData(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("ProjectPlan");
  var ac = ss.getActiveCell();
  var ar = ac.getRow();
  var values = ws.getRange(ar,NOTESCOL,1,PERCDONECOL-NOTESCOL+1).getValues();
  values[0].push(ar);
  values = JSON.stringify(values);
  //var values2 = JSON.stringify(values).substring(1);
  //var values3 = values2.substring(0,values2.length -1);
  return values;
}
```

this is in my HTML file...

```js
//Get the task from the project sheet based on the row of the currently active cell
      function getExistingTask(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(aftergetExistingTask).getTaskData();
        
      }

      //Process the task data retreived from the Project sheet and apply values to the form
      function aftergetExistingTask(values){
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(values);
        const sDate = new Date(parsedData[0][4]);
        const fDate = new Date(parsedData[0][5]);
        const sDateFixed = sDate.getFullYear()+"-"+("0"+(sDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+sDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
        const fDateFixed = fDate.getFullYear()+"-"+("0"+(fDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+"-"+("0"+fDate.getDate()).slice(-2); 
        document.getElementById("idWBS").value = parsedData[0][1];
        document.getElementById("idTaskName").value = parsedData[0][2];
        document.getElementById("idResourceName").value = parsedData[0][3];
        document.getElementById("idPercDone").value = parsedData[0][8];
        document.getElementById("idNotes").value = parsedData[0][0];
        document.getElementById("idPreds").value = parsedData[0][7];
        document.getElementById("idFromRow").value = parsedData[0][9];
        if(isNaN(sDate.getTime())){document.getElementById("idStartDate").value = dteStart}else{document.getElementById("idStartDate").value = sDateFixed;};
        if(isNaN(fDate.getTime())){document.getElementById("idFinishDate").value = dteFinish}else{document.getElementById("idFinishDate").value = fDateFixed;};
      }
```

Thanks again!